# Idiom/metaphor for a certain kind of robbing

Tags: idiom-requests, metaphors

I am looking for an idiom or a metaphor that implies or states the act of robbing through violent ways.

The closest metaphor that I could think of (tho, I would strongly prefer to find an idiom) is "Hit people in the head". However, this denotes an act of violence without implying an act of robbery.

Context (example sentence):

> A condition attributed by collective thinking that imposes loneliness to me, and the latter isn’t a volition anymore. However, how can I live outside society? Word would spread everywhere I would go, and I do not have enough money to move to another country. What could I do? _____(*"Hit people in the head"*), deepen myself on a dark path and spend the rest of my days in miserable decadence?

Comment: Maybe you could “*become a **mugger***”

Comment: @Jim I am looking for an idiom or a metaphor which would fit the description.

Comment: Even if it's not a metaphore: What about "**become a ruffian**" (a violent person, especially one involved in crime.) ?

Comment: The  **Become a mugger...** fits the description perfectly, it is a person who uses violence in order to steal things from their victims. *Hit people in the head* is not necessarily a metaphor, heck, it's a  pretty good description of a violent action.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you for your input. "Hit people in the head" is an idiom in my native language that represents exactly what I am looking for, however, in English it has no metaphorical value indeed. Therefore, I am specifically looking for an equivalent since **Become a mugger** and the like are obviously non-metaphorical options.

Comment: Perhaps "**Wallow in crime and violence**" ?

Comment: "Robbery with violence" is a common phrase.

Comment: Plunder? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plunder;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most natural English phrase that would fit your context would be "[Turn to a life of crime](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/a-life-of-crime), deepen myself...."

It doesn't necessarily mean that the subject would fund their new lifestyle through violence, but that they would be living and financing their life outside the law.

You could always qualify it with "Turn to a life of violent crime" if the violent aspect is important.

It's not an idiom as such, but then, as Mari-Lou pointed out, neither is "Hit people in the head"!

Answer (score 1):

Robbing itself is the act of thieving using coercion/force.
So a Robber would be a proper word to.

You can use some alternatives like Marauder/Plunderer

> Maruad
>
> "go about in search of things to steal or people to attack."
>
> Plunder
>
> "steal goods from (a place or person), typically using force"

Comment: Cheers. However, I am looking for an idiom/metaphor which corresponds to the description.

Comment: You could say "Become a Bandit"? /"Become an outlaw"?

Comment: None of them is an idiom or a metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind using a legal term, then "strong arm robbery".

https://www.legalmatch.com/law-library/article/what-is-strong-arm-robbery.html

*Strong arm robbery is a type of specific intent crime of larceny (theft). It is generally committed through the use of a weapon in combination with the threat of force, actual force, or intimidation. Larceny is legally defined a the unlawful taking and carrying away of a person’s property, with the intent to permanently deprive them of the property.
An example of strong arm robbery is when a person robs a bank with the use of a firearm and carries off some stolen cash. Another example is using a weapon to force a victim to hand over something of value, such as a money, wallet, purse, or vehicle*

Comment: I asked this 3 years ago and it seems today it became a popular question haha. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

"Dabble in the art of the [fingersmith](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fingersmith)"

"Help myself to a [five-finger discount](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Five%20finger%20discount)"

Comment: I'm not sure that they both apply to the act of robbing through _violent ways_.